Snowshoe design for satyrs and fauns
Several of my worlds have satyrs and fauns, which are horned human-like (and human-related) bipedal people with a short tail and two-toed ungulate legs like the hind-legs of a deer or antelope, or single-toed ungulate legs like those of a small horse.
Considering that these people exist in a place where there may be snow in the winters and mud in the spring, how might snow (and/or mud) shoes for these people be designed and from what and how would they be made?
The technological level should be considered to be equivalent to Earth's Renaissance era (15th-16th centuries AD).
The ideal answer should be for footwear that is reasonably easy and cheap to construct, using commonly available materials, should be able to support the wearer's weight on deep snow or mud without becoming bogged, and won't disintegrate easily with most of an adult wearer's 60-90kg mass concentrated on an area the size of a single one- or two- toed ungulate hoof about 6-9cm long and 4-7cm wide (the sole digit or both digits of a single foot).
Answers should also address how these snow shoes would be affixed to their wearer's legs so that they won't easily pull off in use, but can be removed by their wearers when necessary.  Answers should also address balance and clumsiness of the increased surface area for people used to having small feet.

There have to be snowshoes for horses

Such a thing already exists
Below is a picture of some antique horse snowshoes.  On most ungulates, the hooves are wider than the "wrist"; so, you can simply insert them into a belt harness and buckle them into place so they do not slide off.  As for shape, keeping them symmetrical is probably going to be easier on an ungulate than long skinny snow shoes like humans use because they are not accustom-to or designed-to roll their steps like we are.
Speaking of rolling your steps, another key feature you will find is that it is strapped around the hoof, not fixed to it like a horseshoe.  That means that it does roll a bit with the foot to simulate a plantigrade step without the horse having to modify its gait. Since your satyrs theoretically have identical or nearly identical feet to horses, these should work for them with little to no modifications.


As for your technology level...
This particular design was invented in the mid-1800s by American pioneers who needed a way to travel in winter, but there is nothing about its construction that was not already well established in the Renaissance.  That said, there are very few known examples of humans using snowshoes during the Renaissance either.  This is because traveling in dangerously deep snow is not a common requirement of the Renaissance lifestyle.  If you lived in the city, you had roads and people who cleared them so that you'd have solid ground to walk on and if you lived in the country, you were a farmer.  You'd have a winter supply of food and firewood set aside for such weather in advance so that you could shelter in place if the snow gets bad enough.
The main cultures that invest heavily in snowshoes are nomadic societies which was simply not the way of things by the Renaissance period. So, if you have satyrs using such things at this tech level, they will likely not be something that many satyrs have, but something only a handful own because they need them for their specific occupations.

+1! I wish I could +2 for the reference to Europe's established civilization vs. the American west which did not have that distinction. The snow roller could also have been invented during either Renaissance or medieval times (I wonder if it was...) - and that would have readily maintained roads even between cities when sleighs were prominently used.

plenty of more northern cultures used snowshoes at the time, like scandinavia, medieval doesnt just mean France and England. viking 1500's snow shoes for horses ( hestetruger) were recently discovered. https://www.theguardian.com/science/2020/apr/16/spectacular-artefacts-found-as-norway-ice-patch-melts

@John No one said Medieval, the OP said Renaissance.  When you look at the snow paintings of Northern Renaissance artists like Jan van Eyck and Pieter Bruege, no one is every wearing snow shoes. Infact, the article you just posted said that they fell out of use in the 14th century, which is before the beginning of the Northern Renaissance.

@Nosajimiki you think people just stopped using snowshoes in norway? Here you can read about the history of hestetruger and how they changed with time, including art from the 1500's. Where is the heaviest use, in timber felling/hauling or any other job that spends a lot of time outside. It is hardly just for hunter gatherers.

@John I'm not saying non-existent anywhere, I'm saying they would have been a rarity in the context of a Renaissance culture, and the artwork of the time supports this claim. This is why I said "So, if you have satyrs using such things at this tech level, they will likely not be something that many satyrs have, but something only a handful own because they need them for their specific occupations."

I would add ice-spikes.. and because its a goat foot, well situated for mountain travel, i would modify it, so its better able to find hold, when applied at a natural angle, standing only on the tip of the toe on a rock chisel.

And again the rennissance is not just france and england, lots of snowshoe art exists from the time, heck I found you  art for HORSEsnow shoes from the tme. and of course you also had skis used by the military throughout the time. here is 16th century depection of snows shoes form men and horses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Swedishnowshoe.PNG

Also if you think renaissance farmers don't have to go outside and work in the winter you have a very modern view of farming.

It is only a Renaissance technology level. It allows anything to be constructed, and can ignore the culture of the time. Regardless a point in favour of your answer.

@John I apologize for my comment pointing out the possibility of things being built in Medieval and Renaissance periods. I think I'm at fault for this debate. Monty only identified the technology level of his world and Nosajimiki only observed an historical fact about the European Renaissance period. The point both of us were making is that nothing stops Monty from using anything we suggested at his proposed tech level. Nothing more. That the Vikings had something even earlier just underscores the appropriateness of the solution. Once again, I apologize for misdirecting the comment chain.

realized I refrenced a link I never included, here https://snl.no/hestetruger is the link to the history of Norwegian horse-snowshoes. https://snl.no/hestetruger

@John In consideration of a the illustrations found of traveling merchants on the Carta Marina of Olaus Magnus, I've amended the claim that "there are very few if any known examples" to "there are very few examples". While I do agree that they would have seen continuous use, there is a clear fall-off in their usage during the Renaissance, and this falloff is most likely tied to technological advancements like better roads and improved farming methods which would have required less outdoor work to be done in the winter months and easier travel without them.

@John Nothing I've said is wrong.  There was a clear decline in snow shoes in the Renaissance, and a resurgence in popularity in the mid-1800s tied to American expansionism.  All your comments have said is that that they were still sometimes used in specific places and occupations which I also said in my original answer.  You've made many great clarifying statements, but that is very different than proving me wrong.

To be clear, the reason I went with the American1800s horse snow shoe instead of the Medieval Viking design is because the 1800s design does a better job of answering the OPs question about addressing balance and clumsiness of the increased surface area.  The medieval wicker snowshoes would not have rolled with the step the way that the American open hoof, buckled snowshoes did.

@JBH Thanks for the link to snow rollers... I would have never expected that such things existed, and they would fit my world very well, given its small size.

@Nosajimiki nobody (but you) said Renaissance culture though. OP just said tech level. With a culture that is very obviously demanding snow shoes (for humans and horses)., because that is literally OPs question. (horse) snow shoes being found before the Renaissance period makes them plausible within Renaissance tech level (because that is just an upper limit). We're tralking about satyrs and fauns here

@Hobbamok But technology influences culture.  Asking how a Renaissance society would make snowshoes is a lot like asking what kind of wine skins they would use or how they made bronze.  It is not that these things did not exist in the Renaissance, but they were rare because Renaissance advancements in barrel making and iron working made them rare.  My point was not to say they don't belong in his setting, only advice for how to handle their inclusion.

@Nosajimiki except nobody was asking how a renaissance society would do anything, I am bewildered how you keep ignoring this, nobody (but you) is talking about a renaissance culture (or society). That is exclusively the tech ceiling.  And since the entirety of human-animal relationship will diverge significantly, I'd doubt that mapping renaissance culture onto this world will do much good.

@Hobbamok Certain aspects of culture are necessary prerequisites of certain technologies. To make Renaissance technology possible, you need urbanization which required certain advancements in agricultural and logistical technologies which make snowshoes unnecessary in most contexts.   Nomads may need snow shoes for every man, woman, and child but they will never be able to make St. Peter's Basilica, fluted plate armor, or a printing press and sedentary cultures generally don't work their fields or travel long distances when the ground is covered in snow.

Modular horseshoes
There is a good chance that satyrs and fauns will try to ease their movement over land. Especially if they start with hardened roads they'll want to reduce the wear on their hooves. In the real world we have a solution for our horses. Horseshoes. These immediately run parallel to shoes, allowing a reader to easily identify with them, though they have their interesting quirks.
A horseshoe is very hard to easily switch compared to a shoe, so we won't be able to just slap on a winter horseshoe and call it a day. If you make a slightly more complex horseshoe you can make it so you can attach things. It can be as simple as holes for rope, or a more complex form where something can slot in to. The winter option is roped to the holes, or slotted in, allowing for quick switching between winter and non winter situations. About as easy as taking off a laced shoe.
There is the question of what to make the winter part from. I would opt for simple designs that increase the surface area and are relatively lightweight. Think a small wooden circle with wide ropes in a regular pattern, like a tennis racket. These designs are then also adjustable to an individual. A one size fits all kind of deal. That will allow 'mass production' while having no requirement of high skill labour. Each can be different in size and shape and still fit after a fashion.
The only trouble is the horseshoe, requiring a higher standard of manufacturing. You can potentially skip this in favour of just knots around the ankle. I saw some high heels that had strings going up the calves, though some sandle designs also allow for comfortable ropes around the ankle area. Again, highly customisable.
Add animal skins if you require warmth.
